# kvm:vga driver vbempg cause blue screen in guest os Windows XP

Tags: kvm-switch

I don't know if the problem was well know,I searched the google,but didn't get anything useful.

I configed the KVM guest vga mode as

> vga std

and got a yellow exclamation sign with the vga in the XP guest OS.

so I found the vbempg.zip in the follow address:

> http://forum.ubuntu.org.cn/download/file.php?id=45928&sid=b394b9ca338fdca59a4174c5ee4dee26

Some often,I could get a blue screen crash.Any one could give some further information?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the virtio drivers from 
http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers
the latest drivers can be found here: http://alt.fedoraproject.org/pub/alt/virtio-win/latest/images/bin/